# Android: Open Google Map (Fragment inside my app) with traffic detail

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to display all traffic detail within my app on Map fragment 
As for now I'm using google intent

```
Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse

    ("geo:0,0?z=15&q=traffic+on+map");
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            startActivity(mapIntent);
```

For map fragment I am referring this 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map
How do I enable traffic layer on this?

Answer (score 3):

You want to display traffic layer on your Google map fragment

use your googleMap object and

```
googleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true);
```

for ref

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#setTrafficEnabled(boolean)

Comment: Perfect and neat answer.